# Circle between two buttons - show half circle on one and half on other using CSS only

Tags: html, css, shapes

[circle over two buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4F25.png)
I want to have a circle between two buttons and show a half circle on one and a half on other using CSS. I have searched this but nothing appeared to be similar to this. I have to do this only with HTML and CSS.

So far I'm able to do this but Circle is not showing over the right-side button.[What I have done][2]

I have tried everything in my knowledge and search but it seems to be difficult for me.

Any possible solution? I need a solution only using CSS and HTML.

```css
.container {
  margin: 50px;
}

.button1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
  
  margin-right: 5px;

  background: linear-gradient(to right, #142f42 50%, #ff511a 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: right bottom;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}

.button1:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #142f42 100%, #ff511a 100%);
  
  background-position: left bottom;
}

.text1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 30px; 
  color: black;
  transition: all .6s ease-out;
  display: block;
}

.text1:hover {
  color: white;  
}


.button2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 34px;
  display:inline-block;
        
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  margin-left: 5px;
        
  
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #ff511a 50%, #142f42 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: left bottom;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}

.button2:hover{
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #ff511a 100%, #142f42 100%);
  background-position: right bottom;
}

.text2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 30px; 
  color: white;
  transition: all .6s ease-out;
  display: block;
}

.text2:hover {
  color: black;  
}

   
.circle{
    
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #fff;
         
  position: relative;
    
  margin-left: -16px;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  align-self: baseline;
  display: inline-block;
    
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
    
  padding: 0.675rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.8;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.3rem #c0c0c0;
       
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button1">
    <div class="text1">Order</div>
  </div>

  <div class="circle" />

  <div class="button2">
    <div class="text2">Order</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="circle" /> must be <div class="circle" ></div>

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not close circle div correctly `<div class="circle" />` is wrong. It makes button two being rendered inside circle. I have corrected that.

Then I make the following changes to your css:

```css
/* css */
.button2 {
/* remove or unset bottom */
bottom:unset;
/* move button2 to the right */
left: 250px;
}
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 50px;
}

.button1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
  
  margin-right: 5px;

  background: linear-gradient(to right, #142f42 50%, #ff511a 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: right bottom;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}

.button1:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #142f42 100%, #ff511a 100%);
  
  background-position: left bottom;
}

.text1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 30px; 
  color: black;
  transition: all .6s ease-out;
  display: block;
}

.text1:hover {
  color: white;  
}


.button2 {
  left: 250px;
    
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 34px;
  display:inline-block;
        
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 5px;
        
  
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #ff511a 50%, #142f42 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: left bottom;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}

.button2:hover{
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #ff511a 100%, #142f42 100%);
  background-position: right bottom;
}

.text2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 30px; 
  color: white;
  transition: all .6s ease-out;
  display: block;
}

.text2:hover {
  color: black;  
}

   
.circle{
    
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #fff;
         
  position: relative;
    
  margin-left: -16px;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  align-self: baseline;
  display: inline-block;
    
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
    
  padding: 0.675rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.8;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.3rem #c0c0c0;
       
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button1">
    <div class="text1">Order</div>
  </div>

  <div class="circle"></div>

  <div class="button2">
    <div class="text2">Order</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah my bad. Thanks a alot.

Answer (score 0):

This is a clue `<div class="circle"></div>`

```css
.container {
  margin: 50px;
}

.group-button {
  position: relative;
}

.button1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #142f42 50%, #ff511a 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: right bottom;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}

.button1:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #142f42 100%, #ff511a 100%);
  background-position: left bottom;
}

.text1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: black;
  transition: all .6s ease-out;
  display: block;
}

.text1:hover {
  color: white;
}

.button2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: -3px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #ff511a 50%, #142f42 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: left bottom;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}

.button2:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #ff511a 100%, #142f42 100%);
  background-position: right bottom;
}

.text2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  transition: all .6s ease-out;
  display: block;
}

.text2:hover {
  color: black;
}

.circle {
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  margin: -16px;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  align-self: baseline;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0.475rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.8;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.3rem rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="group-button">
    <div class="button1">
      <div class="text1">Order</div>
    </div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="button2">
      <div class="text2">Order</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. you saved me. :)